# Is array of temporaries possible?

Tags: c++

Move supports to steal temporary object's internals to avoid copying. Is it possible to create raw array of temporary objects? i.e. vector does not belong to this category.

```
struct Employee{};

Employee{}; // this creates temporary
Employee [10]; // compiler error, expected identifier before numeric constant
```

Comment: How do you intend to use it if it does not have a name?

Comment: What's wrong with passing a vector around?

Comment: @tadman There is [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1F5lcq4DHAjBwo6A).

Comment: @PasserBy Interesting, but *why*? This seems wildly over-complicated.

Comment: @tadman If you don't want an extra allocation and `std::initializer_list` is inappropriate, you might want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there can be materialized array prvalues. You need to use a type alias though, as the type specifier for the case `T{}` must be a single identifier:

```
using array_t = Employee[10];
array_t{};
```

The prvalue can undergo array-to-pointer conversion too, e.g.:

```
void func(Employee const* ptr);
// ...
func( array_t{} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The only good way to prolong the lifetime of the temporary is to get and hold reference to const to it.

Something like this might work

```
using Ecref = const Employee&;

Ecref a[10] = {Employee("John"), Employee("Mary"), ...};
```

But, unfortunately, arrays of references (const and non-const as well) are forbidden in C++.